# parameter packs not expanded with ‘...' -- another variadic template bug with gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

gcc's treatment of variadic templates is well known to be patchy (see for example [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253) and [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47226)), but I wonder whether the following bug is already known (I cannot find it at bugzilla) or whether it is indeed a bug. Essentially, gcc (4.8.1) fails to expand a parameter pack inside a lambda:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename F, typename... X>
void bar(std::vector<T> const&c, F const&f, X&&... x)
{
  std:for_each(c.begin(),c.end(),[&](const T&t)
         { f(t,std::forward<X>(x)...); });
}
```

this causes (even without any instantiation)

```
error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
  { f(t,std::forward<X>(x)...); });
                        ^
```

any idea how to avoid that? (note: okay with icpc 14.0.2 and clang 3.4) Or is gcc correct after all and clang & icpc wrong?

*edit* Note that the problem is the lambda, as also this doesn't compile:

```
template<typename T, typename F, typename... X>
void bar(std::vector<T> const&c, F const&f, X&&... x)
{
auto func = [&](const T&t){ f(t,std::forward<X>(x)...); };
std:for_each(c.begin(),c.end(),func);
}
```

with the "error" report in the lambda defiition.

Comment: What is the first parameter passed  `t`?

Comment: @Manu343726 What does it matter? The error reports even with no instantiation. [**See it live**](https://ideone.com/BVtPl0)

Comment: Random suggestion: `[&x...]` do anything?  Or stuff them in a `tuple<X&&...>` before pulling them out with an `std::get<Is>(tup)...`

Comment: @Yakk Why should `[&x...]` help? I could try the tuple trick, but I'm afraid the compiler will not optimise that away ...

Comment: @walter Just stabs at workarounds: the compiler is wrong.

Comment: It's been fixed a long time in 4.9, along with a lot of other stuff. Go ahead and upgrade, it must be nearing release by now.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I'm not the sysadmin, can only request update of full releases, not pre-release beta versions. *It's been fixed a long time* -- not really: according to bugzilla it has been fixed 6 months ago but was know for 5 years. Moreover, I gave up upgrading 4.9 on my laptop, since I ran into one ICE after another ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that **the code compiles cleanly with** both clang version 3.5 (trunk 202594) and more importantly with **gcc version 4.9.0** 20140302 (experimental) (GCC), both with `-Wall`, I would say it was an issue with the earlier versions of gcc.

I am looking for a gcc bugreport at http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ to confirm this.

Comment: Honestly said: I don't know which bugreport could be relevant. The codes in [GCC doesn't expand template parameter pack that appears in a lambda-expression](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47226) and in [lambdas and variadic templates don't work together](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41933) fail in gcc version 4.9.0 20140302 but pass in clang 3.5. I am unable to decide which, possibly other, bugreport could be relevant.

Comment: It's [41933](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41933), since I try to capture the entire pack into one lambda and not make another lambda for each member of the pack, each capturing one. According to bugzilla this one is fixed in 4.9

Comment: @Walter What makes me unsure is that this: The codes in that 41933 *do fail* with my gcc version 4.9.0 20140302 but your code doesn't. The failures are perhaps OK because that bugreport was closed on March 4, that is, 2 days after I checked out the source of gcc. It is possible that I checked out a version without the bugfix, hence the failures. That's probably fine. But if it is so, your example should fail as well but it doesn't. That's why I am confused and not sure whether 41933 really is the relevant bugreport or not.