# gcc 4.8.4 error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I'm getting an error with the following bit of [code](https://github.com/emil-e/rapidcheck/blob/master/include/rapidcheck/gen/Container.hpp#L491):

```
template <typename Container, typename... Ts>
Gen<Container> container(Gen<Ts>... gens) {
  using Strategy = detail::GenericContainerStrategy<Container>;
  detail::ContainerHelper<Container, Strategy> helper{Strategy()};

  return [=](const Random &random, int size) {
    return helper.generate(random, size, gens...);
  };
}
```

Here is [travis build log](https://travis-ci.org/bitcoin/bitcoin/jobs/237245298#L490).

From the log, it says we are using gcc 4.8.4 to build this module. This seems to support parameter packs.

```
Configuring rapidcheck...

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info

-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done

-- Detecting C compile features

-- Detecting C compile features - done

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

-- Detecting CXX compile features

-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

-- Configuring done

-- Generating done
```

So I am unsure of why this build is failing with gcc.

Comment: Show us your [MCVE].

Comment: Looks like it's [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41933) as explored in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22568642/560648). Lambdas and variadics don't mix in 4.8, apparently.